# Spring security removes RemoteUser from httpServletRequest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Trying to implement sso using apache. Added auth in apache and it sets username in spring boot applications httpServletRequest.getRemoteUser() through ajp.

Once spring security dependency added to the boot project not able to get the remote user from httpRequest.

```
@GetMapping("/sso")
    public String test(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {

        String u1 = request.getRemoteUser();

        return "--" + u1 + "--" + headers.toString();
    }
```

u1 gives username sent from Apache when spring security dependency is not added

Given permit all for all the request in spring security config

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
```

In Apache added a user from command and added below lines to auth in the virtual host

```
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got a way to get the user from httpRequest.getRemoteUser() with spring security.

Added a filter to invoke before spring security initialization and saved the remote user in request scope for feature use.

Registerd a Filter

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registerRequestLogFilter(SSOFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean reg = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        reg.setOrder(3);
        return reg;
    }
```

and added property

```
security.filter-order=5
```

From filter saved the user value in request score later did auth using it.